# Blazor WASM protected with Azure Active Directory can't call protected WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, blazor

im currently working on a Blazor wasm webapp which is protected with Azure Active Directory and a WebAPI which is also protected with AAD. The APP itself also calls the MSGraph API to get basic user informations.

What is currently working:
The user cannot access the page if hes not authorized, if hes not authorized he gets redirected to microsoft page to login/get authorized. After accessing the page, i'm also able to get basic user information via msgraph following this tutorial : [Official MS GraphAPI Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/graph-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and adding a GraphClientExtension class.

My WebAPI:

[image: API Azure Config 1]
[image: API Azure Config 2]

API Startup :

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => 
                    builder.WithOrigins("*")
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader());
            }); 
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "X.Y.API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "X.Y.API v1"));
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        }
    }
```

The controller/Endpoint I want to call:

```
 [Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
    

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

AzureAD Settings

```
 "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<company>.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "d3c98095-xyz",
    "ClientId": "a51b0337-xyz",
  }
```

My APP :
[image: Azure APP Settings 1]
[image: Azure APP Settings 2]
[image: Azure APP Seetings 3]

Blazor Wasm:

Program.cs :

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
        AddMsIdentityAuthentication(builder);
        AddMsGraphServices(builder);
        AddHttpClients(builder);
        
        AddExternalServices(builder);
        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }

    private static void AddHttpClients(WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<LocalHttpClient>(client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ProtectedAPIHttpClient>(client =>
     {
         client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
     });
    }

    private static void AddMsIdentityAuthentication(WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
        {
            builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
            options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("a51b0337-xyz/Read");
            options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
            
        });
    }
    
    private static void AddMsGraphServices(WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddGraphClient();
    }

    private static void AddExternalServices(WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddTelerikBlazor();
    }
}
```

ProtectedAPIHttpClient

```
 public class ProtectedAPIHttpClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _http;

        public ProtectedAPIHttpClient(HttpClient http)
        {
            _http = http;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetDataTest()
        {
            try
            {
                var test = await _http.GetStringAsync("WeatherForecast");
                Console.WriteLine(test);
                return test;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                if(e is HttpRequestException ex)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine((int)ex.StatusCode); 
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

App.razor :

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

RedirectToLogin :

```
@inject NavigationManager _navigation

@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _navigation.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(_navigation.Uri)}");
    }

}
```

authentication:

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action">
    <LoggingIn></LoggingIn>
    <LogInFailed></LogInFailed>
    <CompletingLoggingIn></CompletingLoggingIn>
    <LogOut></LogOut>
    <LogOutFailed></LogOutFailed>
    <LogOutSucceeded></LogOutSucceeded>
    <CompletingLogOut></CompletingLogOut>
    </RemoteAuthenticatorView>

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public string Action { get; set; }

}
```

AzureAD Config:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/d3c98095-xyz",
    "ClientId": "b02ce171-xyz",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  },
```

I've also added @attribute [Authorize] to _Imports.cs

Ive been wrapping my head around this for days now. If I delete/comment out the API Scope "options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes" in the program.cs everything is working: The user gets forced to login and can navigate around the app (and get user information like the picture,first name etc from msgraph). However if I add the DefautAccessTokenScopes a login to the page is simply not possible. Its in some kind of login-redirect-loop. Ive also tried to use AdditionalScopesToConsent instead but its the same result. Ive followed a lot of tutorials and in most of them configuring the app/api like that should be enough for a simple protected api call example..but it seems im misunderstanding something. Does anyone have a idea or know what im doing wrong?

Comment: If you get rid of 'options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";' will it work with a popup? aka the default behavior of the msal client

Comment: @8protons It wont work if I get rid of LoginMode="redirect",the login window appears and after a login try I get the error "Login not possible, try again".. So basically the same error as redirect just the difference that redirect does multiple tries.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my solution working similar to this, what I found is that App.razor should not contain `NotAuthorized` section und `AuthorizeRouteView` this should be in the MailLayout.razor or Index.razor etc. under `AuthorizeView`.

App.razor sample:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <CascadingBlazoredModal>
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </CascadingBlazoredModal>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

On some *.razor page:

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="@($"{PermissionLevel.XYZ}")">
        <Authorized>
          <p>You are able to see the page</p>
          <p> Even more content</p>
        </Authorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Comment: After trying to move the NotAuthorized and RedirectToLogin to the MainLayout the App is stuck on a white Page with the Url "https://localhost:6001/authentication/login?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A6001%2F"

Ive changed the App.razor like u mentioned and changed my Mainlayout to the following :
`<div>
    <TelerikRootComponent>
      <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
          @Body
          </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
          <RedirectToLogin />
        </NotAuthorized>
      </AuthorizeView>
    </TelerikRootComponent>
</div>`

Comment: I think that is what `options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";` does